# Sprite Colliding With Screen Bottom?

Tags: ios, iphone, collision, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

My scene has a `[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect: self.frame]`. How can I make an action when a sprite collide only with the bottom of the screen?

Comment: You should add node to represent bottom edge, and add physics body to that node. And catch collision on that body.

Answer (score 1):

So, create a body that represents only the bottom of the screen with `` `SKPhysicsBody ``'s `bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:toPoint:` message. Something like:

```
const int buffer = 100;
SKPhysicsBody *myBody = [bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(-buffer, screenHeight) toPoint:CGPointMake(screenWidth + buffer, screenHeight)];
```

Notice the buffer to prevent things from falling off the "edge" until they're off the screen entirely (alter the constant to fit your use case).